# OpenGL 3.3 shaders uniform variables not working

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I've got two shaders programs (because I'm using deferred shading), each one with its Vertex and Fragment shader.
My problem is that I can successfilly compile and link both of them (glGetProgramiv with GL_LINK_STATUS returns GL_TRUE for each one) but when I try to get the addresses of my second shader program's uniforms I can get only 3 of them, instead of 27 that are currently declared.

I've checked with glGetProgramiv and GL_ACTIVE_UNIFORMS to check the number of uniforms for each shader program and for the first one it's right, but for the second it's wrong.

I've noticed that the only uniforms I can get from the secondo program are the first 3 of its vertex shader, and even if I add an uniform in that vertex shader, the number of readable uniforms is always 3.

(I've added only my uniform's declaration because the shaders were too long.)

This is the code for the first program vertex shader (working correctly)

```
uniform struct Matrices
{
    mat4 projectionMatrix;
    mat4 modelMatrix;
    mat4 viewMatrix;
    mat4 normalMatrix;
} matrices;

layout (location = 0) in vec3 inPosition;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 inCoord;
layout (location = 2) in vec3 inNormal;
layout (location = 3) in vec3 inTangent;
```

This is the code for the first program fragment shader (working correctly)

```
uniform sampler2D gSampler;
uniform sampler2D gSamplerBump;
uniform vec4 vColor;

uniform float       gMatSpecularIntensity;
uniform float       gSpecularPower;
uniform float       gRetroilluminato;

uniform int useTexture;
uniform int useTextureBump;
uniform int fondiTextureColore;
```

And these are the vertex and fragment shaders that are not working properly.

Vertex:

```
uniform struct Matrici
{
    mat4 projectionMatrix;
    mat4 modelMatrix;
    mat4 viewMatrix;
} matrici;
```

Fragment:

```
uniform struct MDLight
{
    vec3 vColor;
    vec3 vPosition;
    vec3 vDirection;  

    float fAmbientIntensity;
    float fStrength;

    int bOn;

    float fConeAngle;
    float fConeCosine;

    float fConstantAtt;
    float fLinearAtt;
    float fExpAtt;

    float fAltezza;
    float fLarghezza;

    vec3 vUp;
    vec3 vRight;
} gLuce;

uniform float gSpecularIntensity;
uniform float gSpecularPower;

uniform sampler2D gPositionMap;
uniform sampler2D gColorMap;
uniform sampler2D gNormalMap;
uniform vec3 gCameraPos;

uniform vec2 gScreenSize;
uniform int gLightType;

uniform int gUsaLuci;
```

Basically I can get only the addesses of projectionMatrix, modelMatrix and viewMatrix in the uniform struct "Matrici" of my second program vertex shader.
I've tried adding a value both inside the struct and outside but it doesen't read it.

Anyone with an idea?

---

As @rems4e asked these are the complete shaders.

Vertex shader for working program.

```
#version 330

uniform struct Matrices
{
    mat4 projectionMatrix;
    mat4 modelMatrix;
    mat4 viewMatrix;
    mat4 normalMatrix;
} matrices;

layout (location = 0) in vec3 inPosition;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 inCoord;
layout (location = 2) in vec3 inNormal;
layout (location = 3) in vec3 inTangent;

smooth out vec2 texCoord;
smooth out vec3 vNormal;
smooth out vec3 vTangent;
smooth out vec3 vEyeSpacePos;
smooth out vec3 vWorldPos;

void main()
{
    vec4 vEyeSpacePosVertex = matrices.viewMatrix*matrices.modelMatrix*vec4(inPosition, 1.0);
    gl_Position = matrices.projectionMatrix*vEyeSpacePosVertex;

    texCoord = inCoord;

    vec4 vRes = matrices.normalMatrix*vec4(inNormal, 0.0);
    vNormal = vRes.xyz;

    vec4 vResTang = matrices.normalMatrix*vec4(inTangent, 0.0);
    vTangent = vResTang.xyz;

    vEyeSpacePos = vEyeSpacePosVertex.xyz;

    vec4 vWorldPosVertex = matrices.modelMatrix*vec4(inPosition, 1.0);
    vWorldPos = vWorldPosVertex.xyz;
}
```

Fragment shader for working program.

```
#version 330

smooth in vec2 texCoord;
smooth in vec3 vNormal;
smooth in vec3 vTangent;
smooth in vec3 vEyeSpacePos;
smooth in vec3 vWorldPos;

layout (location = 0) out vec4 WorldPosOut; 
layout (location = 1) out vec4 DiffuseOut; 
layout (location = 2) out vec4 NormalOut; 
layout (location = 3) out vec4 FlagsOut; 

uniform sampler2D gSampler;
uniform sampler2D gSamplerBump;
uniform vec4 vColor;

uniform float       gMatSpecularIntensity;
uniform float       gSpecularPower;
uniform float       gRetroilluminato;

uniform int useTexture;
uniform int useTextureBump;
uniform int fondiTextureColore;

void main()
{
    vec3 vNormalized = normalize(vNormal);
    vec3 vTangente = normalize(vTangent);

    vec4 vTexColor;
    vec4 vMixedColor;

    if(useTexture == 1)
    {
        vTexColor = texture2D(gSampler, texCoord);

        if(fondiTextureColore == 1)
            vMixedColor = vTexColor * vColor;
        else
            vMixedColor = vTexColor;
    }
    else
    {
        vMixedColor = vColor;
    }

    if(useTextureBump == 1)
    {
        vec3 vNormaleBump = texture(gSamplerBump, texCoord).xyz;
        vNormaleBump = 2.0 * vNormaleBump - vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

        vTangente = normalize(vTangente - dot(vTangente, vNormalized) * vNormalized);

        vec3 vBitangente = cross(vTangente, vNormalized);

        mat3 TBN = mat3(vTangente, vBitangente, vNormalized);

        vec3 vNuovaNormale = TBN * vNormaleBump;
        vNuovaNormale = normalize(vNuovaNormale);

        vNormalized = vNuovaNormale;
    }

    WorldPosOut = vec4(vWorldPos, 1.0);
    DiffuseOut = vMixedColor;
    NormalOut = vec4(vNormalized, 1.0);

    float v1 = 0.0;
    float v2 = gMatSpecularIntensity;
    float v3 = gSpecularPower;
    float v4 = 1.0;

    if(gRetroilluminato == 1)
        v1 = 1.0;

    FlagsOut = vec4(v1, v2, v3, v4);
}
```

Vertex shader for NOT working program.

```
#version 330

uniform struct Matrici
{
    mat4 projectionMatrix;
    mat4 modelMatrix;
    mat4 viewMatrix;
} matrici;

layout (location = 0) in vec3 inPosition;

void main()
{
    vec4 vEyeSpacePosVertex = matrici.viewMatrix * matrici.modelMatrix * vec4(inPosition, 1.0);
    gl_Position = matrici.projectionMatrix * vEyeSpacePosVertex;
}
```

Fragment shader for NOT working program.

```
#version 330

uniform struct MDLight
{
    vec3 vColor;
    vec3 vPosition;
    vec3 vDirection;  

    float fAmbientIntensity;
    float fStrength;

    int bOn;

    float fConeAngle;
    float fConeCosine;

    float fConstantAtt;
    float fLinearAtt;
    float fExpAtt;

    float fAltezza;
    float fLarghezza;

    vec3 vUp;
    vec3 vRight;
} gLuce;

uniform float gSpecularIntensity;
uniform float gSpecularPower;

uniform sampler2D gPositionMap;
uniform sampler2D gColorMap;
uniform sampler2D gNormalMap;
uniform vec3 gCameraPos;

uniform vec2 gScreenSize;
uniform int gLightType;

uniform int gUsaLuci;

vec3 projectOnPlane( vec3 point, vec3 planeCenter, vec3 planeNorm )
{
    return point - dot( point - planeCenter, planeNorm ) * planeNorm;
}

vec3 linePlaneIntersect( vec3 lp, vec3 lv, vec3 pc, vec3 pn ) 
{
    return lp + lv * ( dot( pn, pc - lp ) / dot( pn, lv ) );
}

bool isDavanti(vec3 p1, vec3 p2, vec3 n2)
{
    vec3 p1p2 = normalize(p1 - p2);
    float prod = dot(p1p2, n2);

    if(prod >= 0.0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

vec4 getDirectionalLightColor(const MDLight dirLight, vec3 vNormale, int retroilluminato)
{
    float fDiffuseIntensity = max(0.0, dot(vNormale, -dirLight.vDirection));
    return vec4(dirLight.vColor * (dirLight.fAmbientIntensity + fDiffuseIntensity) * dirLight.fStrength, 1.0);
}

vec4 getPointLightColor(const MDLight ptLight, vec3 vWorldPos, vec3 vNormale, int retroilluminato)
{
    if(ptLight.bOn == 0)
        return vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    vec3 vPosToLight = vWorldPos - ptLight.vPosition;
    float fDist = length(vPosToLight);
    vPosToLight = normalize(vPosToLight);

    float fDiffuse;

    if(retroilluminato == 1 && isDavanti(vWorldPos, ptLight.vPosition, vPosToLight))
        fDiffuse = abs(dot(vNormale, -vPosToLight));
    else
        fDiffuse = max(0.0, dot(vNormale, -vPosToLight));

    float fAttTotal = (1 + fDist * 0.0001 + 0.0000001 * fDist * fDist);

    return vec4(ptLight.vColor, 1.0)*(ptLight.fAmbientIntensity + fDiffuse) / fAttTotal;
}   

vec4 GetSpotLightColor(const MDLight spotLight, vec3 vWorldPos, vec3 vNormale, int retroilluminato)
{
    if(spotLight.bOn == 0)
        return vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    vec3 vDir = vWorldPos-spotLight.vPosition;
    vDir = normalize(vDir);

    if(dot(vNormale, -vDir) <= 0.00 && (retroilluminato == 0))
        return vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    float fDistance = distance(vWorldPos, spotLight.vPosition);

    float fCosine = dot(spotLight.vDirection, vDir);

    float fDif = 1.0-spotLight.fConeCosine;

    float fFactor = clamp((fCosine-spotLight.fConeCosine)/fDif, 0.0, 1.0);

    float fAttTotal = (1 + fDistance * 0.0001 + 0.000001 * fDistance * fDistance);

    if(fCosine > spotLight.fConeCosine)
        return vec4(spotLight.vColor, 1.0)*(fFactor * spotLight.fAmbientIntensity) / fAttTotal;

    return vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
}

vec4 GetRectLightColor(const MDLight luce, vec3 vPosVert, vec3 vNormale, int retroilluminato)
{
    if(luce.bOn == 0)
        return vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    vec3 direzioneLuce = normalize(luce.vDirection);
    vec3 posizioneLuce = luce.vPosition;
    vec3 normaleVertice = normalize(vNormale);

    float w = luce.fLarghezza;
    float h = luce.fAltezza;

    vec3 proj = projectOnPlane(vPosVert, posizioneLuce, direzioneLuce);
    vec3 dir = proj - posizioneLuce;

    vec2 diagonal = vec2(dot( dir, luce.vRight), dot( dir, luce.vUp));
    vec2 nearest2D = vec2(clamp(diagonal.x, -w, w), clamp(diagonal.y, -h, h));

    vec3 nearestPointInside = posizioneLuce + (luce.vRight * nearest2D.x + luce.vUp * nearest2D.y);

    vec3 lightDir = normalize(nearestPointInside - vPosVert);

    float prodDirLmLD = dot(direzioneLuce, -lightDir);
    float prodNVLD = dot(normaleVertice, lightDir);

    float NdotL = 0.0;
    float NdotL2 = 0.0;

    if(retroilluminato == 1)
    {
        NdotL = abs(prodDirLmLD);
        NdotL2 = abs(prodNVLD);
    }
    else
    {
        NdotL = max(prodDirLmLD, 0.0);
        NdotL2 = max(prodNVLD, 0.0);
    }

    float prodottoDot = NdotL2 * NdotL;

    if ( prodottoDot > 0.0 )
    {
        vec3 diffuse = vec3(sqrt(prodottoDot));
        float dist = distance(vPosVert, nearestPointInside);

        float attenuation = (1 + dist * 0.0001 + 0.000001 * dist * dist);

        vec3 light = luce.fAmbientIntensity * luce.vColor;

        return vec4(light * diffuse, 1.0) / attenuation;
    }
    else
    {
        return vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    }
}

vec4 GetSpecularColor(vec3 vPosVertice, vec3 vPosCamera, vec3 vNormaleVertice, const MDLight luce)
{
    vec4 vResult = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    vec3 direzioneLuce = luce.vDirection;
    vec3 direzioneLuceVertice = vPosVertice - luce.vPosition;

    if(gLightType == 1)
        direzioneLuce = normalize(vPosVertice - luce.vPosition);

    if(dot(-direzioneLuce, vNormaleVertice) <= 0.0 || dot(direzioneLuce, direzioneLuceVertice) <= 0.0)
        return vResult;

    vec3 vReflectedVector = normalize(reflect(direzioneLuce, vNormaleVertice));
    vec3 vVertexToEyeVector = normalize(vPosCamera - vPosVertice);
    float fSpecularFactor = dot(vVertexToEyeVector, vReflectedVector);

    fSpecularFactor = pow(fSpecularFactor, gSpecularPower);

    if (fSpecularFactor > 0)
        vResult = vec4(luce.vColor, 1.0) * gSpecularIntensity * fSpecularFactor * luce.fAmbientIntensity;

    return vResult; 
}

vec4 GetMDLightColor(const MDLight ptLight, vec3 vWorldPos, vec3 vNormale, int retroilluminato)
{
    if(gLightType == 0)
        return getDirectionalLightColor(ptLight, vNormale, retroilluminato);
    else if(gLightType == 1)
        return getPointLightColor(ptLight, vWorldPos, vNormale, retroilluminato);
    else if(gLightType == 2)
        return GetSpotLightColor(ptLight, vWorldPos, vNormale, retroilluminato);
    else if(gLightType == 3)
        return GetRectLightColor(ptLight, vWorldPos, vNormale, retroilluminato);
}

vec2 CalcTexCoord()
{
    return gl_FragCoord.xy / gScreenSize;
}

out vec4 FragColor; 

void main()
{
    vec2 TexCoord = CalcTexCoord();
    vec4 Color = texture(gColorMap, TexCoord);

    if(gUsaLuci == 1)
    {
        vec3 WorldPos = texture(gPositionMap, TexCoord).xyz;
        vec3 Normal = texture(gNormalMap, TexCoord).xyz;
        Normal = normalize(Normal);

            int retroilluminato = 0;

        vec4 coloreLuce = GetMDLightColor(gLuce, WorldPos, Normal, retroilluminato);
        vec4 coloreRiflesso = GetSpecularColor(WorldPos, gCameraPos, Normal, gLuce);
    }
    else
    {
        FragColor = Color;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`GL_ACTIVE_UNIFORMS` is mapped as its name indicates to the active uniforms, i.e. the ones that actually not optimized away by the shader compiler/linker. This happens when the uniform is not used by your program, or used in a way that won't affect the final rendering.
Your shader code is needed to see if the uniforms you can not get the index of are used or not, but I presume they are not.

Comment: as you can see I use almost all of my uniforms. The ones I'm not using is because I still have to implement their usage, but I'm using more than only 3 of them, and that's for sure I'd say.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem following @rems4e hint.

In fact I thought I was using all my uniforms, in theory, but in practice I wasn't. In all of my functions I was passing a `MDLight` as parameter, which, actually, was `gLuce`, the uniform I was trying to get the uniforms. Seems like that passing `gLuce` as parameter for other functions, OpenGL thought I was actually not using `gLuce`, deleting it from my active uniform list.

So basically I just used `gLuce` everywhere instead the parameter I was passing to the functions and it's now working.

The same for all other uniforms I wasn't able to get.